# Office 365 Calendar Integration

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps

I want to users to grant permission to grant calendar view and scheduling permissions for there outlook/office 365 calendar through my app.
I want to show the office 365 calendar to my application from where users can see their calendar and create or schedule new events. So want to sync the calendar. 
So what is the best way to integration of calendar into the application?
How do I connect my app and permissions for each domain that is using office outlook?
I want to know the best way to integrate it.

I want to integrate like how Drift is integrating it. Like connecting to calendar, showing list of calendar events and meeting, scheduling a new meeting, etc:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to do like this 
https://help.drift.com/article/calendarsetup

https://help.drift.com/article/scheduling

https://help.drift.com/article/outlook-365-calendar-integration

Please help here

Thanks
dalvir

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assume you want to connect the Office 365 and sync the calendar.

We can use the [MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to view the calendar and create or schedule new events.

We can use the following steps to connect the office outlook.

First, we should get an accesstoken to call Microsoft Graph. For more detail information, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview).

Then, we can use  `GET /me/calendars` or `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars` to get the user's calendars.

The following APIs to create a event:

`POST /me/events`
`POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events`

And the following APIs to find the meeting time:

`POST /me/findMeetingTimes`
`POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/findMeetingTimes`

For more information about how to use those APIs, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar).